# Filling ArrayDeques using string causing NullPointerException

Tags: java

I'm currently attempting to write an in-fix to post-fix calculator program and while I was attempting to clean redundant code up I found that depending on how I construct my ArrayDeque's, my program will react differently even though the arrays are similar in contents. I first filled my ArrayDeque using ".add()" repetitively which worked fine, but the I tried cleaning it up by using a string (So I could test equations a lot more efficiently) All of this is done in the testing class below. I also left some comments that may be useful for you.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Deque;

public class EvaluatorTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayDeque < String > inFixEquation1 = new ArrayDeque < > ();
        ArrayDeque < String > inFixEquation2 = new ArrayDeque < > ();

        // Non DRY code: This for some reason doesnt work.
        String equation = "A*(B+C)";
        int temp = equation.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < temp; i++) {
            inFixEquation1.add(equation.substring(0, 1));
            equation = equation.substring(1, equation.length());
        }

        // DRY code: While this does work.
        inFixEquation2.add("A");
        inFixEquation2.add("*");
        inFixEquation2.add("(");
        inFixEquation2.add("B");
        inFixEquation2.add("+");
        inFixEquation2.add("C");
        inFixEquation2.add(")");

        System.out.println("\nCreated inFix equation 1 = " + inFixEquation1);
        System.out.println("Created inFix equation 2 = " + inFixEquation2);

        Deque < String > postFixEquation = Evaluator.infixToPostfix(inFixEquation1); // I switch between the first and second inFixEquations here jsut by changing inFixeEquation1 to inFixEquation2
        System.out.println("\nConverted inFix equation to postFix = " + postFixEquation);
        System.out.println("postFix answer should equal =         [A, B, C, +, *]");
        BigInteger evaluated = Evaluator.evalPostfix(postFixEquation);
        System.out.println("Evaulated postFix equation to BigInteger " +
                "value = " + evaluated + "\n\nProgram end.");
    }
}
```

I also apologize for the messy code, like I said, I was in the middle of cleaning the code up. The code below is the class that does the actual conversions.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.*;

public class Evaluator {

    public static Deque < String > infixToPostfix(Deque < String > in ) {
        Deque < String > inFix = new ArrayDeque < String > ( in ); 
        Deque < String > postFix = new ArrayDeque < > (); 
        Stack < String > storedOperators = new Stack(); 
        Set < String > allOperators = new HashSet < > 
                (Arrays.asList("*", "/", "%", "+", "-", ")", "(")); 

        for (int i = 0; i < in .size(); i++) {
            if (!allOperators.contains(inFix.peek())) {
                postFix.add(inFix.pop());
            } else if (allOperators.contains(inFix.peek())) { 
                if (inFix.peek() == "(" || storedOperators.size() == 0 && inFix.peek() != ")") { 
                    storedOperators.add(inFix.pop()); 
                } else if (inFix.peek() == ")") { // The compiler seems to skip here when inFix.peek() equals ")" if I'm using the first ArrayDeque but not the second.
                    while (storedOperators.peek() != "(")
                        postFix.add(storedOperators.pop());
                    if (storedOperators.peek() == "(")
                        storedOperators.pop();
                } else if (priorityCheck(inFix.peek(), storedOperators.peek())) {
                    while (inFix.size() > 0 && storedOperators.size() > 0 && priorityCheck(inFix.peek(), storedOperators.peek()))
                        postFix.add(storedOperators.pop()); 
                    storedOperators.add(inFix.pop());
                } else if (!priorityCheck(inFix.peek(), storedOperators.peek())) {
                    storedOperators.add(inFix.pop());
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = storedOperators.size(); i > 0; i--)
            postFix.add(storedOperators.pop());
        return postFix;
    }

    public static boolean priorityCheck(String inFix, String auxOp) {
        boolean answer = false;
        Map < String, Integer > opPriority = new HashMap < > () {
            {
                put("-", 1);
                put("+", 2);
                put("^", 3);
                put("/", 4);
                put("*", 5);
                put("(", 1);
            }
        };
        if (opPriority.get(inFix) < opPriority.get(auxOp))
            answer = true;
        return answer;
    }
}
```

So if I run using the first ArrayDeque equation from the testing class I get this error while the second one will run fine, do you know why this is? I know where the null pointer is coming from and why it's coming from this specific place, but I guess I mainly want to know why my program is not catching the last ")" parenthesis at line 19 of my second class when it doesn't act this way when I manually build my ArrayDeque without a for-loop and string.

```
Created inFix equation 1 = [A, *, (, B, +, C, )]
Created inFix equation 2 = [A, *, (, B, +, C, )]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Evaluator.priorityCheck(Evaluator.java:61)
    at Evaluator.infixToPostfix(Evaluator.java:25)
    at EvaluatorTest.main(EvaluatorTest.java:31)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `opPriority` map miss the `)` operator, you can set the `)` priority to 1, like:

```
Map<String, Integer> opPriority = new HashMap<String, Integer>() {
    {
        put("-", 1);
        put("+", 2);
        put("^", 3);
        put("/", 4);
        put("*", 5);
        put("(", 1);
        put(")", 1);
    }
};
```

Then the `EvaluatorTest` output like below:

```
Created inFix equation 1 = [A, *, (, B, +, C, )]
Created inFix equation 2 = [A, *, (, B, +, C, )]

Converted inFix equation to postFix = [A, *, B, C, +, ), (]
postFix answer should equal =         [A, B, C, +, *]
```

**Updated**

For the `inFixEquation1` which run incorrect, it's caused by the way you compare two strings.

For string value compare, you should use `oneStr.equals(otherStr)` instead of `==`. The `==` means compare the string object reference instead of the string value. The correct way like below:

```
public static Deque<String> infixToPostfix(Deque < String > in) {
    Deque < String > inFix = new ArrayDeque< String >(in );
    Deque < String > postFix = new ArrayDeque < > ();
    Stack< String > storedOperators = new Stack();
    Set< String > allOperators = new HashSet< >
        (Arrays.asList("*", "/", "%", "+", "-", ")", "("));

    for (int i = 0; i < in .size(); i++) {
        if (!allOperators.contains(inFix.peek())) {
            postFix.add(inFix.pop());
        } else if (allOperators.contains(inFix.peek())) {
            if (inFix.peek().equals("(") || storedOperators.size() == 0 && !inFix.peek().equals( ")")) {
                storedOperators.add(inFix.pop());
            } else if (inFix.peek().equals(")")) {
                while (!storedOperators.peek().equals("("))
                    postFix.add(storedOperators.pop());
                if (storedOperators.peek().equals("("))
                    storedOperators.pop();
            } else if (priorityCheck(inFix.peek(), storedOperators.peek())) {
                while (inFix.size() > 0 && storedOperators.size() > 0 && priorityCheck(inFix.peek(), storedOperators.peek()))
                    postFix.add(storedOperators.pop());
                storedOperators.add(inFix.pop());
            } else if (!priorityCheck(inFix.peek(), storedOperators.peek())) {
                storedOperators.add(inFix.pop());
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = storedOperators.size(); i > 0; i--)
        postFix.add(storedOperators.pop());
    return postFix;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified a bit more, I understand that this is whats causing the nullpointer exception, however the program shouldn't be able to take the ) operator into the opPriority method as it should be caught in line 19.

Comment: This only happens when I use the DRY code to fill inFixEquation2, (I commented this in so you can see it better) if I use the non-DRY code then it works perfectly and even prints        

Converted inFix equation to postFix =  [A, B, C, +, *]
postFix answer should equal =         [A, B, C, +, *]

Comment: Ok, Make sense, i updated the answer, please take a look again.